# I'm trying to get records from an excel file directly from sql server but its not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

```
Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 656
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "Sheet1$". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.
```

when calling the stored procedure from api, it works fine. but when i execute it directly from sql server, it gives this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
used this link
     try this:
```

https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/